# Как менять картинку в зависимости от часа?

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть несколько картинок которые нужно загружать в зависимости от текущего часа. Можете помочь с функцией которая текущий час узнает? Но без JQery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью объекта Date

```js
let whatHour = new Date().getHours();

console.log(whatHour)
```